# how to draw in the console (c#)

Tags: c#, console, nested-loops

recently in IT class we were provided with a simple console program that used a nested loop to draw a right angled triangle. I don't really understand what is happening in this piece of code. could someone explain how it works and how to create other shapes in the console? here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Task_4
{
    class nestedLoop
    {
        static void Main(string [] args)
        {
            int i, j;
            i = j = 0;
            for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
            {
                for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write('*');
                }
                Console.Write("\n");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The purpose of Stack Overflow isn't to explain code I'm afraid.

Comment: This is not really a suitable question for this site. You really ought to go to your teacher to ask for a clearer explanation of how the code works.

Comment: also, if there are other methods i could use to draw shapes in the console other than nested loops let me know

Comment: Have you actually tried modifying anything in the code to see what different shapes you get?

Comment: my question was mainly how can i draw in the console. the code was really only for visually displaying what i meant by drawing in the console

Comment: i haven't really tried to modify it much because i'm not sure what i would modify to make a different shape

Comment: Jack, if you change" j <= i" in the second for loop to j <= 5 you will get a square.
By setting it to a number bigger than 5, you will get a rectangle with a longer width than height, or if you change i's max value to be larger than j's max value you will get a rectangle with a larger height

Comment: Then you should go run through some basic C# tutorials to understand what is going on here.

Comment: Well - just try it & see. It's not like you are going to cause the end of the world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two for loops, each loop has a variable, i or j assigned to it that will increase by one, until it reaches its upper limit, (i <= 5) or (j <= i). Using this logic, the first loop i is 1 so j will just be 1, then we do the loops again, this time i is 2 so j will run twice, and so forth, below is a small example

Loop 1, i = 1 j = 1 *

Loop 2, i = 2 j = 2 **

Loop 3, i = 3 j = 3 ***

Loop 4, i = 4 j = 4 ****

Loop 5, i = 5 j = 5 *****

So once we have drawn the stars we end up with this.

**Square**

```
For(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
   For(int j = 0; j < 5; i++)
      Console.Write("*");
}
```

**High rectangle**

```
For(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   For(int j = 0; j < 5; i++)
      Console.Write("*");
   Console.Write("\n");
}
```

**Long rectangle**

```
For(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
   For(int j = 0; j < 10; i++)
      Console.Write("*");
   Console.Write("\n");
}
```

Comment: makes sense. so it writes a character, increments, then loops back and starts again till the condition is met?

Comment: Yes. Since, the loop J is inside the Loop I, the J loop will run until the condition of I is met and therefore finished.

Comment: Ive added some other examples.

Answer (score 1):

The outer loop for the variable i loops trough 5 times. Each loop the nested loop with the variable j will set as many '`*`' as the i loop's amount of loops and a linebreak at the end. 
Therefore if it's the first loop of i the j loop wil set 1 '`*`' on the second loop '`**`' and so on. 
Which will result in the following output:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

Answer (score 0):

replace i with row
replace j with column
you should be able to figure it out from there on

but essentially the program can be translated as:

0a) initialize i on 1.

0b) initialze j on 1.

1) On row I, draw a star if J is smaller or equal to I and then add 1 to J.

2) Repeat 1) until J is larger than I.

3) If J is larger than I, add 1 to I, repeat from 0b) until I = limit (5).

Sidenote: cleaner code would be like this

```
using static System.Console;

namespace ExamPrep
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int maxHeight = 5;

            for (int height = 0; height < maxHeight; height++)
            {
                for (int width = 0; width <= height; width++)
                {
                    Write('*');
                }
                Write("\n");
            }
            ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

might want to replace 'height' with 'currentHeight', but the intention is clearer than just using letters anyway.